# How to find a function to describe this series of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have a series of inputs and outputs:

```
input output
----- ------
1     3
2     7
3     10
4     13
5     17
6     20
7     23
8     27
9     30
10    33
...
```

As you can see, the right most position of the output is always 3, 7, 0, 3, 7, 0 ...
How to find a function `f(x)` to describe this relation so that I know f(11) is 37 and f(12) is 40 etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just the nearest integer version of $\frac {10}3x$

Comment: How to get the nearest integer of the three numbers 0, 3 and 7?

Comment: For example, for $x=4$ we have $\frac {10}3 \cdot 4=13.33333\ldots$  When we round to the nearest integer we get $13$.  It works for the $0$ and $7$ as well.  Try it.

Answer (score 1):

You define f(x) recursively. The algorithm is add three then four then three and repeat. So you must define the relationship f(n+1)=f(n)+q. where $q\in \{3,4\}$ depending on what $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Explicitly if $n$ is congruent to $0$ or $2$ then $q=4$, otherwise add $3$. Notice f(n+1)=f(n)+4 if $n\in\{1,4,7,10,..\}$.